# Unity 5.3.8 2d objects not visible

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity . My system didn't support unity latest version so had to download this version from the archieve.however when i am building a 2d project I am unable to find any 2d objects except for sprite.pleases do help. (PFA)

[Screen Shot of Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tl3X.png)

I tried downloading from other version.When installing the new version getting crash when project loads

Comment: your machine didnt support it? ouch, even my crapolaptop which was <400 runs unity - honestly, you will struggle with something thats 5+ years out of date

Comment: What kind of 64 bit system are you running that doesn't support a sensible version of Unity?

Comment: `Unity 5.3.8` was released June 13, 2017 ... over 8 years ago! I don't remember but maybe there was no other 2D objects back then? ^^  Go get a decent PC/laptop otherwise you anyway won't be happy developing anything yet alone compiling/building

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your project build is aligned with what you want to do? Set the default behavior to 2d, or try to reset the layout.

If that doesn't work, you can also create an empty object and add your components to it, it's slower but it works.

I'd try installing a new version if you can solve that problem of yours, but if nothing works, reinstalling may also work.